# How to build javafuse on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, gcc, ld, fuse

I'm trying to implement the [JavaFuse project](https://code.google.com/p/javafuse/) but when I execute the make command I'm getting this error:

```
gcc -shared build/contextClass.o build/conninfoClass.o build/javafuse_jni.o build/statvfsClass.o build/fsClass.o build/utimebufClass.o build/fileinfoClass.o build/statClass.o -o build/libjavafuse.so
```

Error:

> build/contextClass.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: *** [libjavafuse.so] Error 1

I'm using Ubuntu.

Could anyone please suggest what is the problem?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a project with last commit 3 years ago (and the one before that - in 2009) to compile.

Comment: The linker complains that it doesn't like the object files. Can you show the rest of the make output?

Comment: this is the full make output

Comment: the linker is complaining. Did you actually compile or were the .o files already present?

Comment: gcc -shared build/contextClass.o build/conninfoClass.o build/javafuse_jni.o build/statvfsClass.o build/fsClass.o build/utimebufClass.o build/fileinfoClass.o build/statClass.o -o build/libjavafuse.so
build/contextClass.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libjavafuse.so] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

I recommend fuse-jna, it's a project that I've used and it doesn't need to be compiled and also, it's alive and you may find it here [fuse-jna](https://github.com/EtiennePerot/fuse-jna). hope it'll help you